# How to use a WFS DescribeFeatureType request with group name instead of layer name in MapServer

Tags: request, mapserver, wfs

I'm trying to make a WFS request to get information from multiple layers (10 layers) in one request by use the group name of those layers, using MapServer.

I'm using DescribeFeatureType for this.